# git pull from fetch head / unavailable server

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

Before losing internet access I ran `git fetch --all` to fetch all branches.

> With a connection to the server now unavailable, how can I do a `git pull`?

```
$ git checkout feature.a
Already on 'feature.a'
Your branch is behind 'origin/feature.a' by 7 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

$ git pull
ssh: Could not resolve hostname unavailable.example.com: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: `pull` is just `fetch` followed by `merge`. so all you need to do now is `git merge origin/branch mybranch`?

Comment: That worked perfectly. I honestly did not realize that pull executed a merge, and I though that `origin/x` went to the origin _at that point_. Huh. This makes comeple sense now. If you want to add this as an answer, I will accept. I read this before the other posted answer..

Comment: Sure thing, will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What `git pull` does is a `fetch` followed by a `merge`, so, if you already did the `fetch`, you can do `git merge origin/feature.a`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `pull` is just a `fetch` followed by `merge`, you should just be able to `git merge origin/feature.a feature.a` and be good to go.